# Capistrano deploy fails due to missing manifest file when using assets prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I've just set up a Capistrano deploy for our application and I keep running into this error:

```
  * executing ["ls /path/to/app/shared/assets/manifest*"]
    servers: ["web03"]
    [web03] executing command
[err :: web03] ls: /path/to/app/shared/assets/manifest*
[err :: web03] : No such file or directory
```

If I manually create a manifest file with `touch /path/to/app/shared/assets/manifest.yml`, the deploy script works fine. However, this feels all sorts of sketchy.

I've googled the heck out of this and the most I can gather is that the manifest file it's looking for is a product of the asset pipeline. I checked and I do, in fact, have the pipeline enabled (`config.assets.enabled = true`), so I'm at a loss.

Could someone please help me understand 1) what this manifest file is and how it's created; and 2) why isn't one being created for my application?

**Update**: I think I'm closing in on the answer and I think it has something to do with this line:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"
```

We needed to rename the "asset" path because we have Asset objects in our system and I'm guessing Cap might be getting confused because of it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My suspicion was right: this was a problem with the renamed asset directory. Cap didn't know to look in `public/some_other_path` instead of `public/assets`.

In other words, because this line is in my `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.prefix = "some_other_path"
```

I had to add this line to my `deploy.rb`:

```
set :assets_prefix, "some_other_path"
```

Then, Cap knows where to look for a manifest, copies it into `shared/assets`, and finishes correctly.

It'd be handy to have the `deploy.rb` reference the `config` variable instead of having to hard-code the path a second time, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

if you configure with the aws, here it should be...

`appname/config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
config.assets.prefix = "/#{ENV['APP_NAME']}/assets"
```

`appname/config/deploy.rb`

```
...
set :keep_releases, 5
set :assets_prefix, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}/assets" }

set :whenever_identifier, -> { "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
...
```